# классы и интерфейсы в c#

Tags: c#, классы, интерфейс

Здравствуйте. Какая разница между созданием экземпляра класса от интерфейса ? Например (пример взят с msdn), необходимо получить объект Lookup.

```
class Package 
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public long TrackingNumber { get; set; }
}
public static void LookupExample()
{   

List<Package> packages = new List<Package>
{ 
new Package { Company = "Coho Vineyard", Weight = 25.2, TrackingNumber = 89453312L } 
};   

Lookup<char, string> lookup = (Lookup<char, string>)packages      
         .ToLookup(p => Convert.ToChar(p.Company.Substring(0, 1)),           
          p => p.Company + p.TrackingNumber); }
```

Здесь экземпляр packages класса Package явно преобразуется в класс Lookup<>. А в следующем примере:

```
public static void LookupExample()
{   

List<Package> packages = new List<Package>
{
new Package { Company = "Coho Vineyard", Weight = 25.2, TrackingNumber = 89453312L } 
};   

ILookup<char, string> lookup = packages                           
           .ToLookup(p => Convert.ToChar(p.Company.Substring(0, 1)),                                                                                      
           p => p.Company + p.TrackingNumber); }
```

Используется интерфейс ILookup и преобразование происходит неявно. И еще раз к вопросу: Какая разница между созданием экземпляра класса от интерфейса ? И почему во втором случае не нужно явное приведение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если взглянуть на определение метода ToLookup

```
public static ILookup<TKey, TElement> ToLookup<TSource, TKey, TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector
)
```

Видно, что типом возвращаемого значения  является ILookup то есть интерйейс. Соответственно, в случае

```
ILookup<char, string> lookup = packages                           
    .ToLookup(p => Convert.ToChar(p.Company.Substring(0, 1)),                                           
        p => p.Company + p.TrackingNumber);
```

явного преобразования одинаковых типов не требуется . Однако, когда происходит присвоение интерфейса к реализующему его классу

```
Lookup<char, string> =ILookup<char, string>
```

преобразование осуществляется явно. Нужно заметить, что при присвоении класса к интерфейсу, который он реализует

```
ILookup<char, string> =Lookup<char, string>
```

явное преобразование тоже не нужно.